# flexible query method/function for MongoDB + Express using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on an API with MongoDB+Express+Node.js. So far so good, I can query for one record by ID, I can query for a specific field, delete, add, etc.

I am looking for a method that can be called to create a generic query for mongoDB, where i will pass it a json representation of the model with 'some' data to search for. If the field is not specified in the json object, then it will only search on those fields specified.

Here is the boilerplate code I had, done, but I am very new to JavaScript and Node, and I think i need to parse or sanitize the query object before running the .find method.

Basically I want to be able to perform a query similar to how it is done in parse.com where you send an object model with the data you want to search for and you get all the results that match.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

--This code is in my custom module--

```
exports.findByQuery = function(req, res) {
    var query = req.query;
    db.collection('artists', function(err, collection) {
            collection.find(query).toArray(function(err, docs) {
            res.send(docs);
        });
    });
};
```

--This is the routes file--

```
var express = require('express'),
    artist = require('./routes/artists');

var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));     /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

app.get('/search/', artist.findByQuery);
app.get('/artist/:id', artist.findById);
app.post('/artist', artist.addArtist);
app.put('/artist/:id', artist.updateArtist);
app.delete('/artist/:id', artist.deleteArtist);

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what is really being asked here. For simple use cases, it looks like the code you have here would work. Are you running into problems? Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Thanks Bret. This returns all documents in the database, not the query I ask for. If replace the (query) variable with an actual object directly (as in {field:value}  I get the correct query return. It looks like the object being passed as the query is not being liked by the find method (express method).

Comment: This is generally known as "query by example" . Should be enough references to be found .

Comment: I understand. But I am guessing that my issue has to do on how the query object is being passed to the find method. Any more details would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that the code above DOES work, however you cannot search for _id for some reason.. But any other field would work. Still looking how to incorporate _id in the search.

Comment: The reason is that _id is a BSON (binary) representation if the ID not a String... So in my actual method I do an introspection to check if the query is for an ObjectID, in which case I convert the string from the json query to BSON and then search against it.